# BlobstoreService serve() doesn't provide Content-Length

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-chrome, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I want to serve files stored on Google Cloud Storage (GCS) via Google App Engine (GAE) to users. I'm using code below:

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/myBucket/myObjectName");
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);
```

I do not want to expose direct public URL because files are private and only accessible via GAE application. Users can download them only if they are logged in.

However, `Content-Length` is removed from response (so there is no progress bar in Chrome) even if I do

```
response.addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(gcsObject.getSizeBytes()));
```

or

```
response.setContentLength((int) gcsObject.getSizeBytes());
```

before actual serving of the file (first block of code).

Response I'm getting from the server is following:

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
cache-control:private
content-disposition:attachment; filename="MyVideoFile.mp4"
content-type:video/mp4
date:Mon, 21 Apr 2014 10:06:03 GMT
expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
server:Google Frontend
status:200 OK
version:HTTP/1.1
```

When there is no `Content-Length` Chrome (`Version 34.0.1847.116 m`) sometimes corrupts the file - for ex. if file is 180MB sometimes it's 178MB, sometimes 179MB etc. I don't know if those two are correlated.

All files I'm serving are in 100-250MB file size range.

If I put the file publicly and serve it via direct URL (via `https://storage.googleapis.com/...`) I get `Content-Length` and actual progress bar (in Chrome) and everything works just fine (no corruption).

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4310).

If this is a public file then, as you already mentioned, you can serve it via direct Cloud Storage url.

However, if this is a private file, then you can use [GCS Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) to read blob contents and serve it via your servlet. Then `Content-Length` header will be set by GAE automatically.

Comment: If I'm using GCS Client Library and serving it directly (copying byte array to response using `copy(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel), response.getOutputStream());`) I get 32MB HTTP limit error on App Engine. Is there some boilerplate/template servlet/code for files larger than 32MB using `multipart` download or...?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Thats a hard limit on GAE frontend instances.

Comment: In this case you should use direct Cloud Storage Urls and look into ACLs for non-public access: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol